# How can I use languages (like arabic or chinese) in a QString?

Tags: c++, c, qt, qstring

How can I use languages (like arabic or chinese) in a `QString`?

I am creating a `QString`:

```
QString m = "سلام علیکم";
```

and then I am saving it into a file using:

```
void stWrite(QString Filename,QString stringtext){
    QFile mFile(Filename);

    if(!mFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append |QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QMessageBox message_file_Write;
        message_file_Write.warning(0,"Open Error"
                                   ,"could not to open file for Writing");
        return;
    }
    QTextStream out(&mFile);
    out << stringtext<<endl;
    out.setCodec("UTF-8");

    mFile.flush();
    mFile.close();
}
```

But, when I open the result file I see:

```
???? ????
```

[image: see img]

What is going wrong? How can I get my characters to be saved correctly in the file?

Comment: You need Unicode and UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Comment: use unicode because some other language like arabic and chines, japanese alphabet take more than one byte for a single char

Comment: NO...i do it but not working ....

Comment: You should set the code *before* you write. And of course you need a viewer that can decode UTF-8. How do you view the contents of the file?

Comment: like this??

out.setCodec("UTF-8");
QTextStream out(&mFile);
out << stringtext<<endl;

Comment: if you are on windows just make this example: `char czTxt = "سلام"; MessageBox(0, czTxt, 0, 0);` it works ok because win32 uses unicde

Comment: @Raindrop7 I assume you mean `char*`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: yes that is it. sorry it was a mistake

Comment: no--no--nooooooo

i writ on this file with the this:

QString okcombo       =ui->comboBox->currentText();
and he was not work with the:
QChar okcombo       =ui->comboBox->currentText();
?????????????????????????????????

Comment: @Raindrop7, it should be `WCHAR* czTxt = L"سلام";`. `L` means unicode string literal, `WCHAR` means the using wide characters. And after that you should make sure you call the unicode version of `MessageBox` (that is `MessageBoxW`) , otherwise you should have UNICODE defined (or it will not compile).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QString`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#details) has unicode support. So, there is nothing wrong with having<sup>*</sup>:

```
QString m = "سلام علیکم";
```

Most modern compilers use UTF-8 to encode this *ordinary string literal* (You can enforce this in C++11 by using `u8"سلام عليكم"`, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)). The string literal has the type of an array of `char`s. When `QString` [is initialized from a `const char*`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#initializing-a-string), it expects data to be encoded in UTF-8. And everything works as expected.

All input controls and text drawing methods in Qt can take such a string and display it without any problems. See [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/internationalization.html#languages-and-writing-systems) for a list of supported languages.

As for the problem you are having writing this string to a file, You just need to set the encoding of data you are writing to a codec that can encode these international characters (such as UTF-8).

From the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#operator-lt-lt-12), When using `QTextStream::operator<<(const QString& string)`, The string is encoded using the **assigned codec** before it is written to the stream.

The problem you have is that you are using the `operator<<` before assigning. You should `setCodec` **before** writing. your code should look something like this:

```
void stWrite(QString Filename,QString stringtext){
    QFile mFile(Filename);

    if(!mFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append |QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QMessageBox message_file_Write;
        message_file_Write.warning(0,"Open Error"
                                   ,"could not to open file for Writing");
        return;
    }
    QTextStream out(&mFile);
    out.setCodec("UTF-8");
    out << stringtext << endl;

    mFile.flush();
    mFile.close();
}
```

---

<sup>*</sup> In [translation phase 1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases), Any source file character not in the *basic character set* is replaced by the *universal-character-name* that designates the character,The *basic character set* is defined as follows:

> N4140 §2.3 [lex.charset]/1
>
> The basic source character set consists of 96 characters: the space
>   character, the control characters representing horizontal tab, vertical tab, form feed, and new-line, plus the following 91 graphical characters:
>
> a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
>
> A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
>
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
> _ { } [ ] # ( ) < > % : ; . ? * + - / ^ & | ~ ! = , \ " ’

This means that a string like:

```
QString m = "سلام عليكم";
```

Will be translated to something like:

```
QString m = "\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645\u0020\u0639\u0644\u064a\u0643\u0645";
```

Assuming that the source file is encoded in an encoding that supports storing such characters such as UTF-8.